# Throwing Validation Exception in Spring boot

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am creating a Spring boot project for testing my rest API (Very Very tiny Project). The Project contains three files.

1) App.java (Main Program)
2) AppConfig (Configuration file)
3) Main Controller (Simple Rest controller)

I added Spring-boot-starter-parent (1.4.0.RELEASE) and spring-boot-starter-web as dependency.

But While executing,getting an exception like follows.

"javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to create a Configuration, because no Bean Validation provider could be found. Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath."

I added the following dependency and the error gone.

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

My question is, what is the root cause of the specific error message? 
Why we are adding the validator?

Answer (score 0):

It means the classloader could only find the API of bean validator. You have to add some implementation package into the classpath.

Like:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-bean-validation
```

Comment: Thanks Shan. But where spring use it while bean configuration. Whether while using spring-MVC, is this validator is mandatory?

Comment: it is not mandatory. maybe any other library are using bean validator?